# Error in SQL syntax for a update query

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to update user settings via an update query, however the fields aren't being updated on the database. I have run a mysql error and found the error but I still cannot spot it. My query is as follows:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id` = $session_mem_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

And the error is saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` WHERE `mem_id` = 11 ``' at line 1

The actual function looks like this:

```
function update_user($mem_id, $update_data) {
$update = array();
array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

foreach ($update_data as $field=>$data) {
    $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
}

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: +1 for using backticks to delimit your column names!

Comment: Can u show us the value in `$session_mem_id`

Comment: @asifsid88 It is 11. The error clearly tells you that.

Comment: Outch! **Do not give example using mysql_* please. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.**

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling me that the `$update` array is empty. As a result, the generated query is:

```
UPDATE `members` SET  WHERE `mem_id` = 11
```

As you can see, this is clearly invalid. You should check to ensure `$update` has at least one element before running the query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't debug by looking at the PHP code that builds a query.  Debug by looking at the query it produces.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id` = $session_mem_id";
// here you can error_log() the $sql string or inspect it in your IDE or whatever
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I suspect that the $update variable doesn't contain valid syntax.  It's either zero elements as @Kolink suggests, or else it's just a list of values, not `column = value` pairs.  So the resulting SQL would be something like this:

```
UPDATE `members` SET 123, 'abc', 'me@example.com' WHERE `mem_id` = 123
```

That would not be valid UPDATE syntax. You need each column named in the SET clause.

```
UPDATE `members` SET col1=123, col2='abc', col3='me@example.com' WHERE `mem_id` = 123
```

If $update is an associative array, and you expect the array keys to be column names, you should know that implode() will not automatically turn it into `key = value` format.  You'll have to do that yourself with [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) or something.

You probably have read about this already, but the mysql_* functions are now deprecated and you should get used to using mysqli or PDO if you're writing new code.  This also gives you the opportunity to use **query parameters**, which makes it easier, safer, and faster to add dynamic values to SQL queries.

Here's how I would write this with PDO and proper use of error checking, query parameters, and whitelisting column names:

```
$members_columns = array("col1", "col2", "col3");
$update = array_intersect_key($update, array_flip($members_columns));
$columns = array_keys($update);
if ($columns) {
  $sql = "UPDATE `members` SET " 
  . array_map(function ($col) { return "`$col` = :$col"; }, $columns)
  . " WHERE `mem_id` = :where_mem_id";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  if ($stmt === false) {
    $err = $pdo->errorInfo();
    error_log($err[2]);
  }
  $params = array_merge($update, array("where_mem_id"=>$session_mem_id));
  $status = $stmt->execute($params);
  if ($status === false) {
    $err = $stmt->errorInfo();
    error_log($err[2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have included the rest of my function in my original post, so it is something to do with how I am declaring my $update?

Comment: Ok, I've read your function, but you're still not checking if the $update_data has zero elements, and you're not inspecting the resulting SQL string after it has been put together by all the dynamic interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `` " WHERE `mem_id` = {$session_mem_id}" ``

Comment: SO Tip: Use multiple backticks if there are backtick inside the code block.